# 2 PCs with same public IP (same LAN) are absolutely connectable?

Tags: networking, udp, ip

We're developing a P2P application that one of the most important goals is to help PCs connect to PCs wherever they are. We've believed for a long time that any 2 PCs that are in the same LAN (having same public IP) will ALWAYS connectable to other. But recently we wonder if that is true, please help us confirm it.

Suppose 2 certain PCs having no firewall or security filter, if they have the same public IP address (2 PCs are in same LAN) then : Will the udp packet from 1 PC sent to the other PC using local IP address always reach the other somehow? (even if 2 PCs are in different subnets or complicated network structure)

CLARIFICATION: "Connectable" means that 2 PCs can exchange udp packets or making tcpConnection to the other using their local IPs (ex: 192.168.1.100 and 10.0.0.123). I want to be sure that "As long as 2 PCs are in same LAN (having the same external IP) they are "connectable". It's important with P2P application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the question was now changed in way that my first question (with all the comments there) does not apply any longer I try to add a new answer. To describe the setup handled in this answer:

```
 PC1 --------- [NAT Router] ---> Internet
 PC2 -------------|
```

PC1 and PC2 (which have different IP addresses) are inside the same LAN and share the same NAT router. Thus any packets from these PC to the internet have the source address of the NAT router and any packets to these PC from the internet must have the NAT router as the target.

The question is: can PC1 and PC2 always communicate with each other **using their shared external IP address** (the one of the NAT router).

The answer is: it depends on the implementation and configuration of the router used. Thus you should not rely on it.

For a deeper explanation I recommend to study how NAT is implemented in the router, especially the part about [NAT loopback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#NAT_loopback) or [NAT hairpinning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairpinning) or NAT reflection which are different names for the same feature which is needed here.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly a clear answer for my question. Just to clarify: If the 2 PCs are somehow can not communicate via the shared NAT-router then they are absolutely unable to directly communicate anyway?

Comment: I'm going to learn about NAT, but please share with me a bit more: Can you please say unofficially in your experience that in common cases (normal routers' settings like in companies, schools, hostpitals... etc) whether 2 PCs are able to communicate or not? Thanks!

Comment: @vantrung-cuncon: since there are always situation where two P2P devices behind some firewall or NAT router cannot communicate with each other you usually have "supernodes" on the public internet which forward the data instead of having a direct communication between the peers.

Comment: @vantrung-cuncon: there are enough cases where two devices cannot communicate directly that all major P2P networks (including Skype and Zeus) include such supernodes.

Comment: Thank you very very much for your kindness. You helped me so much with your erudite knowledge and patience. That's all I expected for the answer !

Answer (score 2):

While Steffan's answer is technically correct, it doesn't address what I read into your question.  This is possible if the router with the external address is doing NAT and supports hairpin routing.

This, of course, assumes your PCs have different local addresses and share the router.

Comment: In worst cases the 2 PCs are in different subnets & having 2 distinct routers in a complicated network design. :) Of course they have 2 different local IP, but may be 192.168.1.100 and 10.0.0.123. Is that something prevents them from connecting the other?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: this is an answer to the original question which asked about two PC having the same IP address. Now that it is more clear what the intended question was this answer does not apply any more. See my other answer then.

The IP address is the unique identifier if you address systems within an TCP/IP network like the internet. If you are trying to send a message to another system which has the same address as you have the message would not even leave your system because it obviously has already reached the intended target already (address matches).

Comment: Well, so... even If the 2 PCs are in 2 different subnets with the weirdest routing-configurations, they are still connectable as long as they have the same external IP ?

Comment: @vantrung-cuncon If that constraint is part of your question it should have been stated. But it appears to contradict the statement that there is no firewall.

Comment: @vantrung-cuncon: as long as you use the peers "external IP address" as the destination of the data and this IP address is the same as the address of the sender it does not matter if their are routers, different subnets etc. Since the target of the destination IP address is local the data will not leave the computer and thus any external setups are irrelevant. To reach systems with the same IP address as yours but in a different network you cannot use their IP address (since it is the same as yours) but there must be some NAT going on.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich : Maybe I start losing your thread of logic. Suppose the extIP="1.2.3.4", you mean that if PC1 with localIP 192.168.1.100 send udp to "1.2.3.4" then "the data will not leave the computer" ? I meant to send udp to PC2's localIP "10.0.0.123". It's meaningless to send udp to localPC using external IP as peerAddress, I think so. Please correct me if I misunderstand anything.

Comment: @vantrung-cuncon: if both PC have the same IP 1.2.3.4 then sending from pc#1 with 1.2.3.4 to the IP address 1.2.3.4 will never leave pc#1 and thus not reach pc#2. Even if you mean with "external IP" not the IP address of the PC but the internet facing IP address of the router used by the PC the situation is not different. If both routers would have the same IP address then router#1 with IP 1.2.3.4 will not forward a packet to router#2 with IP 1.2.3.4 because 1.2.3.4 is a the IP of router#1 itself so the destination is already reached.

Comment: @vantrung-cuncon: it might be that you have a completely different network situation in mind but that is what one can get from your description. It might help to add some specific example and maybe a drawing to your question so that your network setup gets more clear. It is also not clear what you mean exactly with external and local IP. Maybe you mean a setup with two PCs with different IP addresses but in the same LAN which share the same NAT router and thus have the same source IP when connecting to something on the internet?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich : Sorry for my poor description. The important words "having same externalIP means 2 PCs are in same LAN" was missed. Cause I've never seen any 2 different routers having same public(external) IP. Please review my edited question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think what others answered with hairpinning doesn't apply to your situation.
Hairpinning only applies if both host under same network instead of trying to directly connect to each other with their private IP, they tries through their public IP address.

But in the question it said

> "Connectable" means that 2 PCs can exchange udp packets or making
>   tcpConnection to the other using their local IPs (ex: 192.168.1.100
>   and 10.0.0.123).

If they are both under same NAT but in different subnet like your situation it depends on the router they are connected to. If there is a path through router connection between these two hosts then they will always be able to connect with each other. If the routers are not connected properly meaning this is a disconnected/faulty network and for this case all IPs on some subnets will not be able to connect with some other subnet IPs.

So in your situation it all boils down to the router connections that are connecting your subnets.

I think you should read this [blog](http://think-like-a-computer.com/2011/07/18/how-routing-works/) for clearing your confusion about routing between different subnets. IMO that blog is a great article and a must read.

Comment: Thanks for the article in your answer. I'm reading it and find out it's very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I have nothing against the answers given but I would also advise you to use [Cisco Packet Tracer](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_Tracer) for a better understanding of how these devices communicate to each other, you can further be able to experiment with your ideas and get a much clearer picture